# I am trying to install pip on terminal and I always get this error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, error

input  `python -m ensurepip`

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Have you used the `--user` option, or checked the permissions, as suggested?

Comment: @ElhemEnohpi how can i use the ```user``` option on terminal?

Comment: Just use `python -m ensurepip --user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/python` is Python 2 for backward compatibility. Do you really want Python 2? This is an unmaintained version of the language and most libraries aren't compatible with it anymore. The maintained version of Python is `python3`, and it has pip provided with the system, as `/usr/bin/pip3` (at least on Big Sur and up, maybe not on older versions).

You can install Python 3 packages system-wide simply by running

```
sudo pip3 install PACKAGE_NAME
```

You can install Python 3 packages on your account by running

```
pip3 install --user PACKAGE_NAME
```

(Pip will yell that there's a more recent version available. You can ignore that unless you have a very unusual requirement.)

If you've made sure that you need Python 2 for some legacy program, then run

```
python -m ensurepip --user
```

Note that programs installed by Python packages with `pip(3) install --user` are not in the default command search path. If you need those, add `~/Library/Python/VERSION/bin` to your `$PATH`.